# Interpretation of mixed effect models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interpretation

I am trying to build and interpret a mixed effect model. Here is my problem:
We are interested in comparing professional chefs in cost of meals they create adjusting for time they spend on the meal, cost of ingredients, type of food they create, the chef ID and taste score. We have multiple samples from each chef which can be from single or multiple food categories. My understanding is that this is a crossed design with `chef_ID` and `food_type` as my random effects. So, I created the following model:

```
model.chef <- lmer(food_cost ~ ingredient_cost + preparation_time + taste_score + 
                     (1|Chef_ID) + (1|food_type))
```

The model fits fine and the diagnostics look good. The problem is I want to compare chefs in each food type to answer questions like:

- In which food type category, chefs have the most variability with regard to food cost?
- Which chefs are overcharging in each food type when adjusting for time, ingredient costs and taste score?

I don't know how to answer such questions without using a nested design. The model gives me intercepts for each `chef_ID` and each `food_type` but not the interaction between the two. Had I used a model such as:

```
model.chef <- lmer(food_cost ~ ingredient_cost + preparation_time + taste_score + 
                     (1|food_type/Chef_ID))
```

It would have been easily achievable.